# Laravel 8 maatwebsite/excel export dynamic raw query with header

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I've already installed and used with success maatwebsite/excel in Laravel 8, with collections and "static" queries.

Now I have a situation where an admin user can create his own queries and store them on database (table name: exports), with some placeholders, example:

```
select id, name as full_name, is_active as active from users where my_field > #my_field#;
```

I have created an Export model and inside I retrieve the query, replace all the placeholders and then I want to export the results in excel format.

My method is like:

```
public function excel($params = []){
    $query = str_replace('#my_field#', $params["my_field"], $this->query);
    $values = DB::select($query);
    dd($values);
}
```

`$values` correctly contains all the information, but now I need to export them, **with headers** exactly like in the query structure.

**TLDR:** Laravel 8: I'm trying to export a raw query with headers using maatwebsite/excel

Answer (score 0):

A heading row can easily be added by adding the `WithHeadings` concern. The heading row will be added as very first row of the sheet.

```
se Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class InvoicesExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings
{   
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '#',
            'User',
            'Date',
        ];
    }
}
```

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#adding-a-heading-row

Comment: no, this is not an answer to my question. I need a dynamic header, based on the query result